# How to fix load location on the map by React JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

Link images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K63q.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilgKw.png

Hello everybody, I'm trying to get current location in the maps using reactjs. I get markers and I display them on the map. However, a problem occurs is sometimes faulty maps as shown below. How to fix it?
My code:

let search=this.state.search;

```
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
    search.location[0]=location.coords.latitude;
    search.location[1]=location.coords.longitude;
  });
  this.setState({search:search});
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow.
You should edit your post because it's not so clear. Add an image descriptor please

Comment: Link images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilgKw.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K63q.png